# Where/how should I create instance of my class?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie programmer. I have a class named `GravCalc` inheriting from my form class named `Main`. Inside there are numerous methods dealing with different controls. Here is a code example.

```
public class GravCalc : Main
    {
        private static float engineer = 1.0f;

        public void ShowEngineer()
        {
            GravCalc.engineer = 1.1f;
            gravEngineerLabel.Visible = true;
            gravEngineerLine.Visible = true;
        }
    };
```

I would make those methods and class static, but then I wouldn't be able to inherit from `Form` or operate on controls as they are non-static.

In this case I have to create an instance of my class. So I wrote `GravCalc myGravCalc = new GravCalc();` in `Main` class.

Everything is compiling but when I start the program there are created multiple instances of my class till it reaches maximum number of stack frames and therefore `System.StackOverflowException` occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The thing I wanted to do is group all methods and variables concernig one panel into one class. It would be perfect if it could be static. I had made it inherit from `Main` to have access to my controls, but you realized me this not what I wanted.

So is there a possiblity to make a class which can operate on controls? Or should I throw everething into that Form class?

Comment: Why does your GravCalc class inherit from Main? Do you realise that makes GravCalc into a form?

Comment: So `GravCalc` inherits from `Main` and `Main` instantiates a new `GravCalc`?

Comment: b[e]mused is the word alright...

Comment: We are fortunate to exist in a world where space is not limited so much. `GravCalc` seems to be a name unnecessary abbreviated. Don't do that. Spell it out.

Comment: @user414076 GravCalc is pretty clear for me. Are you sure you want GravitonTechnologyResearchSatellitesAndResourcesNeededCalculator?

Comment: Yes. Or at least somewhere between *that* and "GravCalc."

Comment: @user414076: The one and only place where the "descriptive names" rule *doesn't* apply is in product/program names, which "GravCalc" appears to be since it descends from `Main`. So give the guy a break...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from Main to have access to the controls, you should pass the reference to the controls that you need to use in the class into the constructor for GravCalc.

```
public class GravCalc
{
    private ControlType _control1;
    private ControlType _control2;

    public GravCalc(ControlType control1, ControlType control2)
    {
        _control1 = control1;
        _control2 = control2
    }

    private static float engineer = 1.0f;

    public void ShowEngineer()
    {
        GravCalc.engineer = 1.1f;
        gravEngineerLabel.Visible = true;
        gravEngineerLine.Visible = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

GravCalc IS Main... so if in Main you create GravCalc, you are making a Main again, which then makes a main again, which then eventually runs out of stack.

What you want to do is find where the original Main is created and replace it with GravCalc and take out the `new GravCalc` out of your Main

Comment: It would depend on exactly where he wrote the new statement wouldn't it?

Comment: it would,  but by the nature of the exception, its pretty easy to guess where :)